# Passing checkout shipping information to observer

Tags: checkout, event-observer, shipping-address

I'm creating an event that will log information from this page, however, i'm not entirely sure how to log the information contained within this form upon checkout.  So, I plan to dispatch an event that an observer will listen for.  This observer will create an entry in a log file.  Currently I have something that looks like this:

```
<?php
Mage::dispatchEvent(
    'no_quotes_available',
    array(
        'address' => $address,
        'products' => $products
    )
);
?>
```

And within the observer is:

```
    public function log_shipping_error($observer){
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $date = Mage::getModel(‘core/date’)->date(‘Y-m-d H:i:s’);
        $products = $event->getProducts();
        $address = $event->getAddress();
        Mage::log('date: '.$date, null, 'noShipLog.log');
        Mage::log('products: '.$products, null, 'noShipLog.log');
        Mage::log('address: '.$address, null, 'noShipLog.log');
        return;
    }
}
```

My question can be condensed to:  How do I get information relating shipping information from the checkout page to my observer?

What would be the best way to get:

```
$products
```

and

```
$address
```

from checkout?

Comment: I could also send only the information from the checkout form to server via the observer and just fetch the cart on my own.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can send the full quote to the observer and get the data from quote in there

```
<?php
Mage::dispatchEvent(
    'no_quotes_available',
    array(
        'quote' => Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote(),
    )
);
?>
```

You can retrieve the quote in your observer like this:

```
public function doSomething($observer)
{
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $items = $quote->getAllItems();
    $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();
    $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    ....
}
```